# Traducción para "amenities"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

El otro día hablábamos de cosas de hoteles, y quise saber cómo se llamaban los *packs* de jaboncitos y demás que suelen poner en los baños de los hoteles. Mi mujer respondió automáticamente: *amenities*.

Según el Merriam-Webster, un *[amenity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amenities)* es algo que te hace la vida más fácil o agradable. Una traducción podría ser "comodidades". Sin embargo, si buscamos en Google Imágenes tanto "[amenities](https://www.google.es/search?q=amenities&prmd=insv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEleSBlcHOAhXFWBQKHeq7AEQQ_AUIBygB&biw=360&bih=560)" como "[comodidades](https://www.google.es/search?q=amenities&prmd=insv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEleSBlcHOAhXFWBQKHeq7AEQQ_AUIBygB&biw=360&bih=560#tbm=isch&q=comodidades)", los resultados son radicalmente diferentes. La búsqueda del término inglés da justo el resultado esperado, pero no así la búsqueda del término en español.

Así pues, ¿cuál sería el término adecuado en español para "amenities" en el sentido planteado?

Comment: That is interesting, as I think that in English I would have called them toiletries which the internet seems to tell me is _articulos de tocador_. If you asked me where the amenities were I would direct you to _los servicios_.

Comment: @mdewey that's funny. If you search "toiletries" in Google Images you find "artículos de aseo", but the ones you would buy for your house, and not the ones you would find in a hotel room.

Comment: Yo entiendo por _amenities_ las comodidades tales como gimnasios, juegos para los niños, piscinas y demás características adicionales que diferencian un hotel de otros pero no incluiría en ellos los jabones o el gorro para la ducha.

Comment: @DGaleano es muy probable que el término signifique en realidad lo que tú dices, pero que en los últimos tiempos su sentido haya variado al que comento en la pregunta.

Comment: Simplemente aclarar que en inglés _amenity_ sigue teniendo el significado genérico de _comodidades, servicios adicionales, etc._ **más** el de _amenity kit_, mientras que en castellano, _amenity_ se usa casi sólo para esto último. Por eso sólo aparecen los kits en Google.es. Buscando _amenities_ en Google.com en inglés los resultados también incluyen piletas de natación y campos de golf.

Comment: @angus me imaginaba que esto sería así. Entonces el término "amenity" en, digamos, la jerga española es el que representa exclusivamente esto, a falta de otro término. Esto podría ser perfectamente la respuesta a la pregunta.

Comment: Mis padres son cubanos entonces "Take this with a grain of salt". Nosotros decimos *amenidades*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A site specific search using Google and restricted to the Spanish language version of TripAdvisor reveals that of the three candidates suggested:

In bronze medal position with 1310 hits is *articulos de tocador*
In silver medal position with 5480 hits is *articulos de aseo*
and  for all three 
In gold medal position and Olympic champion with 71800 hits is the wife of Carlos with her suggestion *amenities*

I did not look at all the hits (I do have a life) but the top few which I did check are indeed illustrated with pictures of the collection of toiletries which the better class of hotel provides.

Answer (score 1):

Randy Díaz, en su post borrado, propuso *amenidades*.  Me pareció una idea interesante, así que busqué con google `amenidades hotel` y resulta que sí se usa.  Por ejemplo, una compañía que surte hoteles con estos paquetitos [define su misión así](https://servicioshotelerosmx.wixsite.com/amenidades):

> En Servicios Hoteleros contamos con una línea muy completa de productos de bienvenida o amenidades, haciendo más confortable la estadía de sus huéspedes y creando un alto revivir de bellos momentos de su estadía.

Es evidente que la compañía prefiere usar ambos términos, partiendo de la idea de que ningún término por sí solo es universalmente entendido.

Yo personalmente preferiría el primer término, **productos de bienvenida**.  Pero creo que incluyen *amenidades* porque hay muchos que se acostumbran al cognato de inglés.

Chequeé google images, con inspiración del post de @mdewey.  Es interesante.  "Productos de bienvenida" muestra únicamente los jaboncitos, etc., mientras que "amenidades" muestra principalmente otra cosa, y unos cuantos jabones.